# Partial View not executing controller's action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have the following partial view that I am trying to get to call the action("Search") of a controller("Message") that is inside a View ("Message/Create").

I cannot seem to get the controller's action to fire at all. I have tried so many combinations but can not seem to get anywhere with it.

The partial view is meant to have a textbox and button for filtering a HTML table.

### Partial ("_ProfileList.cshtml")

```
@model MyApp.Models.MessagingModels.ViewModels.CreateMessageViewModel
@{
    var altLine = false;
}

<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Messages", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "dvProducts", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
    {
        <label for="Searchbox">Find Profile :</label>
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div id="dvProducts" class="datagrid">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Profile Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfProfiles)
            {
                <tr class='@(altLine ? "alt" : "norm")'>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="SelectedProfile" value="@item.ID" id="SelectedProfile_@item.ID" /></td>
                    <td>
                        @if (item.Favourite)
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/favourite-star.png")" alt="Favourite" />
                        }

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

### CreateMessageViewModel

```
public class CreateMessageViewModel
{
        private List<ProfileModels.DataModels.Profile> _listOfProfiles; 


        public List<ProfileModels.DataModels.Profile> ListOfProfiles 
        {
            get
            {
                using(var ctx = new EFDataContext())
                {
                    var tmp = ctx.Profiles.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
                    //_listOfProfiles = ctx.Profiles.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList().ToPagedList(1, 10);
                    return _listOfProfiles;
                }
            }
            set { _listOfProfiles = value; }
        }


       //..removed for brevity


}
```

### Message View

```
@model MyApp.Models.MessagingModels.ViewModels.CreateMessageViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<div class="grid_12">

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div id="SignupForm">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Profile</legend>
                <strong>What profile would you like to target?</strong>
                 @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ProfilesList", Model); }
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Region</legend>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Message</legend>
                <strong>What type of message do you want to send?</strong><br />
                <div id="message-type-selector">
                    <input type="radio" name="messagetype" value="SMS" id="message-type-sms" checked="checked" />
                    <label for="message-type-sms">SMS</label><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="messagetype" value="Email" id="message-type-email" />
                    <label for="message-type-email">Email</label><br />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="Message-Options-SMS">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SMSMessageText)
                    <br />
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SMSMessageText)
                    <div id="smscharactersremaining">100 characters remaining</div>

                    <button id="check-textarea">
                        Check Spelling
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <span class="loading">loading..</span>



                </div>
                <div id="Message-Options-Email">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailMessageText)
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="EmailMessageText" name="EmailMessageText" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
                    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/jHtmlArea.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jHtmlArea-0.7.5.min.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
                    <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/jHtmlArea.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jHtmlArea.ColorPickerMenu.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
                    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jHtmlArea.ColorPickerMenu-0.7.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>




                </div>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Tracking</legend>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Confirmation</legend>

            </fieldset>
            <p>@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
                <input id="SaveAccount" type="button" value="Submit form" />
            </p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

### MessagesController

```
public class MessagesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EFDataContext db = new EFDataContext();

        public ActionResult Search(string CurrentFilter)
        {
            var model = from p in db.Profiles
                        where p.Name.Contains(CurrentFilter) || p.Description.Contains(CurrentFilter)
                        select p;


            var vmm = new CreateMessageViewModel
                          {
                              ListOfProfiles = model.ToList()
                          };

            return PartialView("_ProfilesList", vmm);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems, but I think the biggest is that you have nested forms.  Your Ajax.BeginForm is rendered within another Html.BeginForm.

Nested tables are not legal HTML and browsers may or may not honor them.

Comment: I moved the `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_ProfilesList", Model); }` above the `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and it is calling the controller's action. I'm now getting brought to the Message/Create URL or route with a blank HTML page. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can keep this inline? Thanks.

Comment: @Seany84 - I don't understand what you mean.  You are talking about behavior that I can't see, or know about based on what you've shown.  Keep what inline?  inline with what?  What does any of that have to do with a blank html page?  It sounds like a complex situation, and might need it's own question.

Comment: Sorry, It's late and I've been stuck on this for a while. I have updated the code above to reflect what I was trying to say previously. What is happening now is when I enter text in the Partial View's textbox and press the submit button. I am brought to a non-styled page that only has the partial view on it. i.e. http://localhost/Messages/Create/ that only has the Partial View's HTML elements on it and I have lost the actual View's HTML elements.

Comment: @Seany84 - You shouldn't update your questions with new questions.  You should ask a different question.  The reason is that questions are intended to be archival, so that people can look at them in their original context.  If you keep modifying it, then the original context is gone and the question no longer makes sense.. or gets lost in multiple other questions.  You've received the answer to your question as to why the submit wasn't working.  Formulate a new question, with new information that's relevant to the new question.